# lightning-combox performance issue when specified the value?

Tags: lightning-combobox

I noticed when i have more than 20 items and set up to select previously selected item the lightning Combobox freezes it is common problem?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar issue.  It might be related to Lightning Locker.  If the array that you are passing in as options is wrapped in a proxy, then there will be performance issues.  I fixed this by converting the options into a normal array before passing it to the `lightning-combobox`.
e.g.

```
const optionsNoProxy = [];
proxiedOptions.forEach(option => {
    optionsNoProxy.push(option);
});

this.options = optionsNoProxy;
```

Comment: After doing a lot of try and errors however I do pass the array to the childcomponent lwc will wrap the array with proxy instead I decided to pass as string by json.stringify to the child componnet and parse that in the child component so it is much more faster.

Comment: @ShinyaKoizumi you saved me! This was exactly the issue for me. My pattern now is to check if the `options` passed in is an Array, and if not an Array but a String, parse it.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your answer.  I tried on my own to figure out what was happening here or how to workaround it, eventually opened a case with Salesforce and they sent me this post.  converting the options into a normal array allowed us to work around it.

Comment: Hi @scottstone . can you please share the post. I am struggling with slowness of the combobox. The options are nonProxy. I did JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) , however there is no improvement